# combination of `hover` with `word_split` and `tooltip`

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to combine `hover` with `word_split` and `tooltip`, so that when any word is hovered, a tooltip with different info can appear? (example - the translation of the word)

Can anyone show me how to do that correctly?
Below 2 codes that I was trying to combine:
text separation:
http://jsfiddle.net/3HdKH/
hovering text:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip

I will be grateful for help.

Comment: adding some code to show us what you tried so far would be nice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To better help you, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sure, sorry guys. It's my first time here, future questions will be better prepared :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written you an example that combines the two different examples you posted.  There's a snippet that you can run below, which shows it in action.

So here's an explanation:

Since the `lettering` library splits your words into individual spans, with a class of `word1, word2, word3...` I use jQuery's "attribute starts with" selector (https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and then a `hover` handler on each one.

```
$("span[class^='word']").hover(...)
```

The `hover` method takes two functions, one for when you hover over the item, and another for when you move your mouse off. (https://api.jquery.com/hover/)  Inside those jQuery methods, `$(this)` refers to the item itself (in this case, each `<span>` surrounding each word).

When you hover over a word, I add a class of `tooltip` to the span, and append a new `div` of class `tooltiptext`, and then add some content.  Since I don't know what you want your tooltips to read, I just put in "tooltip content".   *NOTE: This is where it's going to be hard to have dynamic data for each word, but you could do it with an AJAX lookup, or maybe a dictionary function, or whatever, which gives you your tooltip content...  That part will be up to you...*

This is the code that does that:

```
function() {
  $(this).addClass('tooltip').append('<div class="tooltiptext">tooltip content</div>');
}
```

Then when you stop hovering over the word, the second function takes over, which removes the tooltip class, and removes the new div:

```
function() {
  $(this).removeClass('tooltip').find('div').remove();
}
```

So hopefully this gets you started with what you need!

```js
$(".word_split").lettering('words');
$("span[class^='word']").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('tooltip').append('<div class="tooltiptext">tooltip content</div>');
  }, 
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass('tooltip').find('div').remove();
  }
);
```

```css
.word_split span:hover {
    font-weight:bold;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/downloads/davatron5000/Lettering.js/jquery.lettering-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
<p class="word_split">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris suscipit interdum fermentum. Aenean fermentum imperdiet augue, et venenatis lectus semper vel. Phasellus faucibus nulla in quam egestas eleifend. Cras tristique augue eget libero tristique condimentum. Mauris eget diam eget risus feugiat rutrum. Duis placerat lorem quis augue semper porttitor. Nullam iaculis dui feugiat erat condimentum rutrum. Sed at accumsan diam. Maecenas ut urna id velit posuere auctor in vel dui. Aenean consectetur dui in leo faucibus sed feugiat dui blandit. In accumsan diam vitae erat volutpat volutpat aliquam nunc euismod. Vivamus viverra lorem nulla. Quisque justo quam, adipiscing sit amet auctor non, laoreet sit amet nisl. Donec euismod lorem ac mi dictum volutpat. Donec ligula mi, varius ac auctor at, sollicitudin id elit. In auctor sodales ipsum nec consectetur. Sed lacinia varius nibh vitae vulputate.<p>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much, you're very kind, I couldn't ask for a better explanation.